# What does it mean to write X=Y+W where W is gaussian with mean 0.

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming X Y are two random variables. When we write X=Y+W with W~Gaussian(with 0 mean), Do we mean the random variable X-Y ~ Gaussian(with 0 mean)? Or does it mean X|y ~ Gaussian(with mean y)? I think the two are clearly not equivalent since the second case seems to imply the first but the first doesn't imply the second.

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting

Comment: Yes, I would also say that $W=X-Y\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ For the second case I´m not sure at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what was intended is that $Y$ and $W$ are independent of each other and $W$ is Gaussian with expectation $0.$ People often omit to mention such an assumption of independence.

Necessarily this would imply that $X-Y$ is Gaussian with mean $0,$ but people don't usually express the situation that way when they intend the hypothesis of independence of $W$ and $Y$ to be tacitly understood.

The thing that you express by saying $X\mid y \sim\text{some distribution}$ is something I would express either by saying $X\mid (Y=y) \sim\text{some distribution depending on $y$}$ (thus $Y$ is a random variable and $y$ is not) or by saying $X\mid Y \sim \text{some distribution depending on $Y$}$ (so that things like $\operatorname E(X\mid Y)$ or $\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y)$ would themselves be random variables that are functions of $Y$).

Notice that if you say that $X\mid (Y=y) \sim \operatorname N(y,\sigma^2),$ that will entail that $X-Y$ is independent of $Y,$ as follows:
\begin{align}
X\mid (Y=y) \sim \operatorname N(y,\sigma^2) \\[8pt]
X-Y \mid (Y=y) \sim \operatorname N(0,\sigma^2)
\end{align}
and the expression $\text{“}\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2)\text{''}$ has no $\text{“}y \text{''}$ in it.

Comment: So basically, I can think of X=Y+W as X|(Y=y) ~ N(y,$^2$) for all y? So the second case in my original question is the true equivalent meaning? Do you mind if I ask one more question. In general, does $X-Y$~$N(0,$$^2$) $  imply  $ X|(Y=y) ~ N(y,$^2$)$ for all y ? I guess the answer is No?

Comment: Correct on both counts. To say that $X\mid (Y=y) \sim \operatorname N(y,\sigma^2)$ implies that $X-Y\sim\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2)$ but it also implies more than that: that $X-Y$ and $Y$ are independent. To say only that $X-Y\sim\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2)$ does nothing to imply they are independent.